# Prove that if $F$ is a nonempty closed subset of $\Bbb R$ and $x \notin F$, then $\exists y \in F$ s.t. $|z-x| \geq |y-x|$ for all $z \in F$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $F$ is a nonempty closed subset of $\Bbb R$ and $x \notin F$, then there exists at least one point $y \in F$ such that $|z-x| \geq |y-x|$ for all $z \in F$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Outline: For $R>0$ call $F_R=F\cap \bar{B}_R(x)$. Since $F$ is non-empty we have that $F_R\neq \emptyset$ for some $R>0$. Clearly any candidate $y$ must be in this $F_R$. Now define $f(z)=|x-z|$ for $z\in F_R$. Since $F_R$ is compact $f$ attains its minimum at some $y$, this $y$ does the trick.

Comment: This is nice.  Do you mind reading over what I did and telling me if there is any way forward? I'm having trouble finishing my proof.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a good start, but as you will see once you get to the end, this solution is not complete, because I am having trouble proving a final statement.

Since $F$ is nonempty and *closed*, that means it contains its limit points.  Let $x \in \Bbb R - F$ (i.e., $x \in \Bbb R$ and $x \not \in F$).

Suppose by contradiction that for each $y \in F$, there is some $z \in F$ such that $|y - x| > |z - x|$.  (What we are saying is that for each $y \in F$, we can find a $z \in F$ that is closer to $x$ than $y$ is).

In particular, if we pick some $y_{1} \in F$ and look at $|y_{1} - x|$, then we can find some $y_{2} \in F$ such that $|y_{2} - x| < |y_{1} - x|$.  But then we can find $y_{3} \in F$ such that $|y_{3} - x| < |y_{2} - x|$.  So, we are a sequence of elements of $F$ that is getting closer and closer to $x$.  If $\epsilon_{n} = |y_{n} - x|$, then $\epsilon_{n}$ represents the distance of the $n$-th term of the sequence from $x$.

Clearly, {$\epsilon_{n}$} is a sequence of real numbers that is monotonically decreasing ($\epsilon_{n} > \epsilon_{n + 1}$) and is bounded from below by $0$, and so it converges.  The only problem now is: does this sequence converge to $0$?  If so, then the sequence $y_{n}$ is getting arbitrarily close to $x$, which would make $x$ a limit point of $F$, and this would be a contradiction since we assumed $x \not \in F$, but we also assumed $F$ is closed (i.e., it contains its limit points).  So we would have $x \in F$ and $x \not \in F$.

I'm not entirely sure yet how to prove $\epsilon_{n}$ does not converge to some positive number.  When I figure it out, I will update this answer.

Comment: The problem is your sequence $y_k$ is too arbitrary: For example take $x=0$, $F=(1,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $y_k=1+1/k$. Then clearly this sequence satisfies all your conditions, but $\varepsilon_k= 2+1/k$. Instead what you want to say is that $\alpha=\inf_{z\in F} |z-x|$ exists and is in $(0,\infty)$; then take $y_k$ so that $|x-y_k| \to \alpha$ and prove that the sequence $y_k$ converges to some point that is a minimizer. Notice that a compactness argument is necessary, since for example this result is not true in an infinite dimensional space.

Comment: @Jose27 Yeah, I realized when I was writing up the proof that somehow, if $F$ were an open set like $(1,2)$, which is not compact, then as in your example we can have a sequence of stuff in $F$ getting closer to some $x$ not near $F$ (without ever converging).  I guess your construction of the compact set $F \cap \overline{B(x,R)}$ was really important.

Comment: @Jose27 Could you show me how to write up the proof using th inf? What I have so far is that Because F is nonempty and closed it contains its limit points. So we will let $x \in \mathbf{R}$ but $x \notin F$. We will define the distance from x to F as $d(x,F)= inf{|z-x|: z \in F}$. I know I need to show that the distance is equal to $0$ which will then imply that $x \in F$. Any suggestions?